# How to remove file extension in a FreeMarker template

Tags: java, freemarker

My Freemarker template is as following: 
`file : ${filename}`

In the java code ***filename*** is a String whose extension can vary: 
    `"the_file_name.ext" or "the_file_name.mpas" or even "the_file_name"`

The result I would like : 
    `file : the_file_name`

Does FreeMarker offer the functionnality I am looking for ? For example : 
`file : ${filename?without_extension}`

Comment: What did you try? Can you post your code to see the mistakes you have done?

Comment: I did not know what to try.. I don't know if Freemarker offers the relative functionnality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with FreeMarker 2.3.22, you can use `${filename?keep_before_last(".")}`. I tested that this even works as expected if `filename` does not contain any `.`.

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_keep_before_last

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, using split : http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split